# Custom Send option with Outlook addin

Tags: office-js, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

Is it possible to create a custom option for "Send," such as 'Schedule Send'?

[image]

option 1:

```
<Hosts>
<Host xsi:type="MailHost">
    <DesktopFormFactor>
        <!-- The functionfile and function name to call on message send.  -->
        <!-- In this case, the function validateBody will be called within the JavaScript code referenced in residUILessFunctionFileUrl. -->
        <FunctionFile resid="residUILessFunctionFileUrl" />
        <ExtensionPoint xsi:type="Events">
            <Event Type="ItemSend" FunctionExecution="synchronous" FunctionName="validateBody" />
        </ExtensionPoint>
    </DesktopFormFactor>
</Host>
```

It is running for every message, but I would like to choose on witch message will run.

Option 2:

```
 <!-- Enable launching the add-in on the included event. -->
      <ExtensionPoint xsi:type="LaunchEvent">
        <LaunchEvents>
          <LaunchEvent Type="OnMessageSend" FunctionName="onMessageSendHandler" SendMode="SoftBlock" />
        </LaunchEvents>
        <!-- Identify the runtime to be used (also referenced by the Runtime element). -->
        <SourceLocation resid="WebViewRuntime.Url"/>
      </ExtensionPoint>
```

Upon installing the add-in, I encounter the issue shown in the image.

[image]

Is it possible to add a third option in the drop-down list with a custom action to insert an email in the system and send?

Comment: Hi, currently  this is not a part of the product. We track Outlook add-in feature requests on our Tech Community Page (https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-365-developer-platform/idb-p/Microsoft365DeveloperPlatform). Please submit your request there and choose the appropriate label(s). Feature requests on Tech Community are considered when we go through our planning process.